# Angular directive that matches multiple names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

How to create an Angular directive that matches multiple names? I have a series of `<div>` elements (a good couple of hundreds) with different IDs. I want to write a single directive which matches only some of those IDs.

A directive like this is not an option since it will be called for all the large number of `<div>` elements I have.

```
directive('div', function(){
   return {
      restrict: 'e',

      link: function(scope, ele, attr) {
         if (attr.id !== 'divX' || attr.id !== 'divY')
            return;

         processElement();
      }
   }
})
```

Also I can't  go on writing directives for all the IDs I need. Adding another attribute to the selected `<div>` elements is not practical either.

Do the angular directives offer any feature that support matching multiple names?

Something like

```
directive('divX', 'divY', function(){
  //...
})
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to do this? If you want to share same controller on some of these divs, you should just replace them with a custom directive, instead of modifying the 'div' directory. If you only need to change the layout of these divs, you can do that using css and make a custom class.

Comment: This is for a modification of an existing application which is quite large. Only some of the divs has to be acted for. I don't want to share anything between these directives. That is not the intention.

Comment: I think any solution would require traversing the collection of `div`s if you insist on using a directive to capture the elements with specific `id`s.

Comment: What I need to know is if that traversing can be done natively by angular itself.

Comment: what you are asking doesn't even make sense.  it would make more sense for your directive to be restricted to attribute ('a') and just add the directive to the HTML of each div you want to process than to try to scan the entire DOM tree for specific Ids.....

Answer (score 1):

Strictly answering your question :

> Do the angular directives offer any feature that support matching multiple names?

If by **name** you mean **id**, then NO, Angular doesn't offer the possibility to associate directive to **ids**, even to a single one.

If you want your directive to target some elements that are **div**, you should add a shared **class** to all those elements, and then use a directive that target this **class** :

```
<div id="divX" class="user">John</div>
<div id="divY" class="user">Paul</div>
```

And

```
directive('user', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, ele, attr) {
      processElement();
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('ui.directives', [])
      .directive('divX', myDirective)
      .directive('divY', myDirective);
```

Will it work in your case ?

Comment: I have very clearly mentioned in my question that this approach is not an option.  ***//Also I can't go on writing directives for all the IDs I need***

Comment: @CharlieH.. what do you mean by matching multiple elements.. using what identifier??

Comment: Angular can match elements for directives for E, A, C or M. That is for a specific name the directive go by. I need to know if there can be multiple names.

Comment: could u explain what u mean by "multiple names"?

Comment: I have updated the question with a hint of what I may be looking for